# jQuery :not selector not working on click

Tags: jquery

The following code is intended to remove class "on" from a li element with the class "left" and "searchbar" when any element other than #target is clicked but it has no effect:

```
$(':not(#target)').click(function() {
  $('li.searchbar.left').removeClass("on");
});
```

Here is the HTML, basically if the user clicks anywhere BUT `#target` it will remove the on class from the li.

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"><a id="target"></a></div>
  <ul>
    <li class="searchbar left on"></li>
  </ul>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: is `#target` added after the page has loaded by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

```js
// if click anywhere on <body> remove class on from given li
$(document).on("click", function() {
    $('li.searchbar.left').removeClass("on");
});

// if click happens on #target do nothing
$('#target').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

#target {
background-color: powderblue;
width: 100px; height: 100px;
}

li.searchbar.left.on {
  color: orange;
}

li.searchbar.left {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
<li class="searchbar left on">hello</li>
</ul>

<div id="target">#target</div>
```

Comment: @Sam in this case: No. Like what you where trying it can not work because you need to listen on something for a click, you can not just kind a say "not that element" that makes no sense. That will only work if you assign it to a parent element and say `:not()` to one of it's children.

Answer (score 0):

For the not selector you have apply it on the similar group of elements.

Like for example from a list of li having class 'selected' but click on that has no 'selected' class:

```
$('.left:not(#target)').click(function() {
console.log("clicked");
});
```

Comment: There is no wild card for all elements?

Answer (score -2):

```
$("body").click(function(ev) {
if(ev.target.id == "target") {
return false;
} else {
// your code
}
})
```

Comment: Could you explain what is happening with the snippet?